Is there a way to detect legitimate screen mirroring on Android and not Android Auto?
As per the title, is there a way to detect when actual screen mirroring is being performed, and not via Android Auto? Some banking apps detect when mirroring and I realise that they also detect Android Auto, which isn't really sheen mirroring.
I know you can detect screen mirroring via DisplayManager.getDisplays() and see if the return value is >1,but would Android Auto register as a display here? If so, are there ways to rule out this false positive?

This approach might work for detecting actual screen mirroring vs Android Auto. Here's a simple solution that should work for most cases:
class ScreenMirrorDetector(private val context: Context) {
  fun isScreenBeingMirrored(): Boolean {
   val displayManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager
        
        // Get all displays
        val displays = displayManager.getDisplays()
        
        // Check each display for mirroring flags
        return displays.any { display ->
            // Simple check for mirror flags
            val isMirror = display.flags and DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR != 0
            // Make sure it's not private (Android Auto usually is private)
            val isNotPrivate = display.flags and DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PRIVATE == 0
            
            isMirror && isNotPrivate
        }
    }
}



To use it in your app:

// In your Activity or Fragment
val detector = ScreenMirrorDetector(context)
if (detector.isScreenBeingMirrored()) {
    // Screen is being mirrored
}

The main trick here is that Android Auto uses different display flags than regular screen mirroring. While both will show up in getDisplays(), Android Auto typically uses private flags, while regular screen mirroring uses the auto-mirror flag.
I haven't tested this, but have seen this in discussion around android auto on Reddit or Discord, I Hope this helps! Let me know if this works 

VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PRIVATE not found. also screen mirror detection not works.

Check this new answer... I have taken help of Gemini for this, but still you should check it.

don't use that kind of tools for posting the answer. SO can easily detect and suspend the account automatically. Thanks for your support. new answer also not works. I will take care
